# Bootstrap Centering Entire Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

So I've googled and tried to trouble-shoot this issue for the past hour and I'm starting to get slightly upset.

I need this navbar (which currently has the entire contents of it to the left): [navbar left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpBfI.png)

to have all of its contents centered to look like this (made in paint, lol.): [navbar center edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrAUq.png)

The only solutions I have ever found to this are either having the nav links centered without the brand or the brand centered without the nav links.

HTML:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header ">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SOUND HAUS</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/articles" style="color:#fff;">ARTICLES</a></li>
            <li><a href="/interviews" style="color:#c00618;">INTERVIEWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="/gallery" style="color:#fff;">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact" style="color:#c00618;">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    font-family: Long Shot;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 998;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: white !important;
}

.navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you include that html src for that bootstrap css file

Comment: @repzero I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Sorry.

Comment: Your sample codes does not reflect exactly what is in your screenshots..try pasting all your codes  from this question into a jsfiddle...see that difference between the screenshot and your codes?....I am thinking your html page contains link tags to external css files  for bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put a container in the nav and then overwrite and add some css rules to bootstrap rules.

```
<style>
.container.nav{
  text-align:center
}
.navbar {
    font-family: Long Shot;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 998;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-header{
  max-width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-header {
     float: none;
  }

}

@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-collapse.collapse{
  max-width: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
}


.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: white !important;
}

</style>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container nav">
      <div class="navbar-header ">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SOUND HAUS</a>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="/articles" style="color:#fff;">ARTICLES</a></li>
              <li><a href="/interviews" style="color:#c00618;">INTERVIEWS</a></li>
              <li><a href="/gallery" style="color:#fff;">GALLERY</a></li>
              <li><a href="/contact" style="color:#c00618;">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

I added only the `div class="container nav"`
Then some of the css rules had to be modified for dimensions bigger than 768px (if less the same remain). And this is a screenshot I made: [image]

Comment: I could kiss you. Thanks so much!